# how do I upload or build a file in VS Script?

Tags: python

I am brand new at writing code and I was trying to use VS Script to edit the config.h file and then compile to upload to my new firmware from Marlin, but I cannot find the command to build or upload the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please give us some context so we can help you better.  How does VS script apply to your Python tag?  What is the config.h file? Neither VS script nor Python require complained code. What firmware?  What is Marlin?  Build and upload what file to where?  We might be of more help locating self organising pink unicorns for the parade tomorrow.

Comment: The program is Visual Studio Code. I am using it to Compile the new Firmware for a new Motherboard on my 3D Printer. Marlin is the name of the Firmware. The config.h file is where you can change the settings to match your Motherboard's setup. I'm sorry, but I have NO idea what programming language it is using.

Comment: Gotcha, ok.  Thanks for explaining.  Perhaps post a section (or all of, depending on its size) of your config file and an example of the output you’d like; and we’ll see if we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you may find detailed instructions [here](https://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/install_platformio_vscode.html).